# R: install.packages("semPlot") does not seem to work

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot, structural-equation-model

I've been trying to use LAVAAN, which means I need to set up "semPlot" first.
However when I try `install.packages("semPlot")` I receive this message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
dependency ‘XML’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘RcppParallel’, ‘StanHeaders’, ‘rpf’, ‘sem’, ‘OpenMx’
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
                binary   source needs_compilation
RcppParallel    5.0.0    5.0.2              TRUE
StanHeaders  2.21.0-1 2.21.0-5              TRUE
rpf             1.0.3    1.0.4              TRUE
sem             3.1-9   3.1-11              TRUE
OpenMx         2.17.3   2.17.4              TRUE
```

I tried `install.packages("XML")` but receive `package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)` My version is 1.1.463 so I'm not sure what's going on.

When I try to summon `library(semPlot)` I get this error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘semPlot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘sem’
```

Can anyone help me decipher this riddle?
Would be super thankful for any advice!

Comment: 1.1.463 is (I'm guessing) your version of RStudio, which has little to do with the R version itself. If you look at the top of the console, you'll see something like `R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"` ... you can also use `sessionInfo()` or even `R.version` to see what your current version of R is. FYI, 3.5.2 was [released in Dec 2018](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/); you might have a little difficulty installing some packages that now require R-3.6 or R-4.0 to be able to function (though you *might* still be able to install from source).

Comment: To install the `XML`package you need to have R ≥ 4.0.0. Update your R software to the latest version.

Comment: thank you all ! updating my R software fixed the problem!!